# How do I disable Windows authentication on a SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security, authentication

How do I disable Windows authentication on a SQL Server instance?

Comment: you're about management studio, or about connection from app?

Comment: oh..i dnt know we can do both management n from app..can u tell me both?thx b4

Comment: oh..i dnt knw about it....so answering , effected hw much we can ask n receiving someone answer..ic

Comment: Since SO has a reputation system based on points, it is the right thing to do in order to motivate folks to answer other questions. Please see the following: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about

Answer (score 3):

if you are about management Studio, please read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx)

You can't remove Windows authentication. You can only remove SQL authentication.If you don't want to use windows authentication, don't create sql login for windows account.

if you are about connection to sql server from applications modify connection string in config files like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create each Windows group/user (that can connect to the box and might access SQL Server) in SQL Server security logins and deny permission and disable the login.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put SQL Server in to SQL logins only mode, but you achieve the same thing by removing all Windows accounts & groups from having access.  If SQL Server logins are all that are setup and there;s not guest permissions configured then you're done.